# Marking databases for a particular setup only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My application security from piracy depends upon fields in my databases. User has to activate the application, that writes Bought in my database. 
But the problem is if a new user installs my application and replaces all databases from some one who has bought key, the application also becomes active without buying key from me.

Is there any possibility that I could mark the databases to be recognized with the particular setup?

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

Since someone is almost always going to be able to find a way to defeat security measures that you put in place, you should aim for a solution that prevents a majority of mostly unsophisticated users from being able to user your software without paying while not making it overly painful for legitimate users.

To that end, I think that storing the status in the database is going to be problematic since it is easy to copy the databases. If you have to do this, your best bet is to get the `MachineGUID` from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography` registry key, then encrypt this value using a dual or one way encryption algorithm and store it in the database.

When your app starts up you can get the MachineGUID and either encrypt it and then compare the encyrpted value with the database value (if one way encryption) or decrypt the database value and compare it with the registry value (if two way encryption).

You will need to provide a mechanism that allows the user to update the registration if they have to move the database to a different machine (i.e. a small windows application), but you could require them to obtain a specific registration code from you before the registration can be changed.

Comment: I did have the same mechanism but my application needs to run over the network and if I use machine key, it does not work on network